# Share documents from MySite with External Users with On-premise SP2013

Tags: 2013, mysites, share, external-users

All is in the title. Is it possible to share my documents stored in `'MySite'` to external users (using mail address for example) ?

I'll be using ARR to external access to SharePoint.

I'm using SharePoint 2013 SP1 (may 2015 cu).

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 On premise version does not have by default the feature to share with external users or customers. we have to extend the site and provide different identity providers.The identity provider can be Active directory,SQL server,Claims,ADFS server which will support liveID.

- [External Users and Sharepoint 2013 - Question on technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64952ea4-6639-4c49-8330-2ac80da42bc3/external-users-and-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral)

But if you are using the SharePoint online then it is easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw this question on technet, so I decided to ask here, I thought someone already walk around that.
The solution from ITG (http://www.itgsharepoint.com/products-external) seems to do what I want, but I can't find any information about pricing.
Do you have any idea on how they achieve this ?

Comment: I mean, maybe I can find or create custom code that would enable this function

Comment: Or maybe you can explain me how does this solution work ... Because I do not understand at all :( it creates some temp AD account ? or SQL without password ?